# exception after `call far TSS descriptor:offset`

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, kernel, mbr

I have a big problem that's got me stuck for a month!
I'm writing assembly code to do a task switch by `call  far [es:esi + TCB.addr_tss]` in bochs, like picture 1.[image]

Now I step into the new task, so I type 's' in bochs, like picture 2:
[image]

For now, everything seems OK, the general registers CS, SS, the cotrol registers CR0, CR3, the LDT is OK too. But do you know what will happen if I step again? See picture below:
[image]

What's wrong?!
I have no idea. I examined DPL, segment limitation, and nothing seems wrong. 
Oh, god bless me...

Comment: Can you upload whole runnable code?

Comment: The preparation is redundant, the code after context switching by TSS is just a `mov   eax, eax`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a big irony, I forget to set access permission to PDE.